# Which operators should I overload to add any amount of values, seperated with commas, to std::vector?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, stdvector

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec += 1,2,3,4;
```

So I want to make the following piece of code add these 4 numbers to std::vector but I have no idea how to overload comma operator to do so.

I know that Boost.Assign allows construction like this, but I want to do this without any additional libraries.

Comment: You cannot overload operators that doesn't take class type as any of the operands.

Comment: Doesn't `vec += std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4};` satisfy you?

Comment: Looks like Boost [assignment library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Comment: But Boost assignment library allows to do so. So how is it done there?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this an abuse of operator overloading, but here's how it can be done.

First of all, note that the precedence of the comma operator is the lowest among all operators in C++.  Therefore,

```cpp
vec += 1,2,3,4;
```

is actually parsed as

```cpp
((((vec += 1), 2), 3), 4);
```

The simplest approach, therefore, is to define both `+=` and `,` to append an element to the vector and return a reference to the vector:

```cpp
auto& operator+=(std::vector<int>& vec, int elem) {
    vec.push_back(elem);
    return vec;
}

auto& operator,(std::vector<int>& vec, int elem) {
    return vec += elem;
}
```

([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e8mbwUjqT1urcE5Y))

A somewhat safer approach is to make `+=` return a proxy object that works with `,`.  The element type can also be generalized.  This is basically what Boost.Assignment does under the hood.

Of course, don't forget to wrap all of this in a namespace, and only import it when necessary.

Comment: Thank You very much <3. I spent so many hours looking for the answer...